# Jquery resize() ignoring scrollbar's width?

Tags: jquery, methods, resize, width, scrollbar

I'm doing a respondive website that will require me to swap my html around using javascript/jquery resize method, these are my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() { 

    if($(document).width() <= 751){
        $('.mainSec').insertBefore('.ourSerAside');
    }else{
        $('.ourSerAside').insertBefore('.mainSec');
    }

});
```

The original condition should be **less than or equal to 768**(since I want to trigger when it is equal 768px....), but it soesnt work. I noticed it is due to the extra width from the scrollbar which is **17px width**.

Is there

Hence 768-17px(scrollbar width)=751px

Is there an easier way to do this, that will ignore the scrollbar's width? Since my code will look quite mess up with different values from the media query from css and javascript all together.....

Answer (score 0):

You could try `$(window).width()` to get the size of the window regardless of scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bet, I'm working on chrome browser and I'm using the developer tool.

The reason I got it wrong is because I'm referring to the width provided by the chrome developer tool (which included the width and scrollbar in the first place).

The width I should be getting is the width of the body not the overall width of the browser